# Can Google Static Maps send back a 3d map/image

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I know [Google Static Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#StyledMaps) can send back a .png map of specified location when I make a specific HTTP request.

**But can it send back a 3d/Photographic map when I make a HTTP request?**

By 3d I mean an image like [Google Earth](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/)

For example, in the following HTTP request is there a query string key I should/can use to specify that I want a 3d map returned?

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=3d

Comment: This isn't a programming question and is better suited to the Google Group (Static Maps are still dealt with in the [Version 2 Group](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/)). But it's answered entirely by the documentation, anyway.

Comment: @AndrewLeach where abouts is it in the documentation? I had already looked and could not find any mention of 3d? Would you be able to link the page?

Comment: The API behaves as described in the documentation. If it's not mentioned, it can't do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no, Google does not provide a static API to 3D Google Earth imagery.

Comment: but it provides for android

Comment: i have seen whatsapp using it

Comment: can you give us an example... like an image, image of what you want, and an example in android...